# How to configure pavuncontrol

Tags: sound, pavucontrol

I am struggling with the configuration of `pavucontrol`. I think I did something to the settings when trying to get `pulseaudio` and `alsa` to play well together. This is what is what I did in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

```
load-module module-jack-sink
load-module module-jack-source
```

I also put this information in the `.bashrc` file.

```
zynaddsubfx -I alsa -O jack -a
```

This is the error that I am seeing: [image: pavucontrol]

Any suggestions on how to get `pavucontrol` working again would be appreciated, thank you very much.

Comment: you can simply reinstall it and purge it to reset to the default configuration with `sudo apt install pavucontrol --reinstall --purge` command line

Comment: I am trying to follow your advice but the terminal doesn't like it. It says "Command line option --purge is not understood in combination with the other options" Could you be more specific?

Comment: you can also decompose this command in 2 parts : `sudo apt remove pavucontrol --purge` which would uninstall and reset pavucontrol, and reinstall it with the classic `sudo apt install pavucontrol`

Comment: `--purge` option will remove all save that your package have done, so it's basically a reset

Comment: OK the terminal took that but there was no change.

Comment: OK I took the same steps except with pulseaudio. Restarted the computer and got the sound to work. If you put your comments in an answer I will vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall `pavucontrol` and reset his parameters to the default configuration :

```
sudo apt remove pavucontrol --purge
```

with `--purge` option in order to do the reset (without it, `pavucontrol` configurations - which can be the issue - wouldn't be removed)

Reinstall `pavucontrol` like we do usually :

```
sudo apt install pavucontrol
```

Restart the computer in order to reload the sound configuration.